# Render View in twig template

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I'm pretty new to Drupal, and very new to Drupal 8.  I've created a view, and have set up it up with a display block.  I'm trying to render this on a specific page.  So, I created a page template and a preprocess hook, created the following function.

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_node__13(&$variables) {
 $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('views_block__downloads_block_2');
 $block_content = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
 $variables['downloads'] = $block_content;
}
```

When I place `{{ downloads }}` in my page template (`page--node--13.html.twig`) nothing happens.

Any ideas what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Use this function  function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {....your code ....} ,if you are creating a page template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the visibility of the block in UI you can use a standard region and the standard page template.

If you want to do this with a specific page template similar to the question, add a region `download` to the theme, place the view block in this region and render the region in the page template specific to the node `page--node--13.html.twig`:

```
{{ page.download }}
```